# Using a touchscreen to Scroll a Panel while dragging the Panel's controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scrollbar, panel, touchscreen

My Form has a scrollable Panel that can be scrolled using a touchscreen monitor.  My Panel will contain a TableLayoutPanel with Buttons inside of it.  I can use a MouseWheel to scroll the Panel fine, no matter where my cursor is.  Using a touchscreen, I can only scroll the Panel when my finger slides over the empty space around my TableLayoutPanel, not within the TableLayoutPanel itself.

Is there a way to pass through anything besides a MouseClick to the underlying Panel?

Ignoring the TableLayoutPanel for now, here is a simplified example of what I've been trying with a Panel and tall Button.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim p As New Panel
    With p
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Width = Me.ClientSize.Width
        .Height = Me.ClientSize.Height

        p.BackColor = Color.LightBlue

        .HorizontalScroll.Maximum = 0
        .AutoScroll = False
        .VerticalScroll.Visible = False
        .AutoScroll = True
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(p)

    Dim b As New MyButton
    With b
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Width = 400
        .Height = 1000

        b.BackColor = Color.LightCoral
    End With
    AddHandler b.Click, Sub() MessageBox.Show("Clicked!")
    p.Controls.Add(b)

End Sub

Private Class MyButton
    Inherits Button

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        Dim HTTRANSPARENT As Integer = -1
        Dim WM_LBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H201
        Dim WM_VSCROLL As Integer = &H115
        Dim WM_MOUSEMOVE As Integer = &H200
        Dim WM_MOUSEWHEEL As Integer = &H20A
        Dim WM_NCMOUSEHOVER As Integer = &H2A0
        Dim WM_MOUSEHOVER As Integer = &H2A1


        If m.Msg = WM_VSCROLL _
        OrElse m.Msg = WM_MOUSEMOVE _
        OrElse m.Msg = WM_MOUSEWHEEL _
        OrElse m.Msg = WM_NCMOUSEHOVER _
        OrElse m.Msg = WM_MOUSEHOVER Then
            m.Result = CType(HTTRANSPARENT, IntPtr)
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

End Class

End Class
```